# The method personY(Agent) in the type Main is not applicable for the arguments (Main._person_Population)

Tags: anylogic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3pD6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEpx6.png)

Error trying to set XY target in fedGoTo4 block How do I solve it

Can't a personX agent be a personX?

I've tried many things, but it doesn't solve the problem How should we solve the problem

Comment: Welcome to AnyLogic and SOF. Some pro-tips on asking better questions: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

There are many (!) things not setup correctly, but your main problem now is to understand the difference between an agent population (`person`) and individual `Person` agents in it.

A population cannot have coordinates. Individuals can.

So to get or set coordinates, call the individual, i.e. `person.get(0).getX()`

Comment: Feel free to share how, helps future users to solve similar issues. Also, if the answer was helpful, pls upvote it